# How to call the other module block in home page in magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: php, magento

I need to display the blog post details in home page . I Have used below extension for post display (https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/nblog-blog-extension-by-neotheme.html).

```
 In my loyout.xml :- 

        <neotheme_blog_index_index>
            <update handle="neotheme_blog_default"/>
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="neotheme_blog/post_list" name="post.list">
                    <action method="setSummaryBlockType"><block>neotheme_blog/post_summary</block></action>
                    <action method="setSummaryTemplate"><block>neotheme/blog/post/summary.phtml</block></action>
                    <action ifconfig="blog/customer/enabled" method="setUseCustomerPreferences"><use_customer_preferences>true</use_customer_preferences></action>
                </block>
            </reference>
        </neotheme_blog_index_index>

In Admin side :-

Home cms page :-  I called the block like 
         {{block type="blog/post/list"   name="post.list"  template="neotheme/blog/post/list.phtml"}}
```

But nothing displays. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your custom block class_prefix/block in

```
Admin -> System -> Permission -> blocks
```

in your case, just add:

```
neotheme_blog/post_list
```

to block permissions

that setting is only for **CMS pages** & **CMS blocks**

Comment: check the correct block class, that one blog/post/list is wrong

Comment: use this neotheme_blog/post_list in {{ }}

Comment: I changed {{block type="neotheme_blog/post_list"  template="neotheme_blog/post/list.phtml" }}.But not working .

Answer (score -1):

Please call block with template like this. As its its possible for me to rectify the error what you have in XML layout. Better you use bt below code directly with phtml page.

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('bannerslider/default')->setTemplate('bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml')->setBannersliderId(1)->toHtml();
```

Also you can call block from CMS page admin.

```
{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/product/form-top.phtml"}}
```